# VS2010 program won't run on Windows server 2008

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008

I have a c++ program compiled in VS2010 using the v100 platform toolset which I try to get to run on a Windows server 2008 but I get the following error:

> Entry Point Not Found: The procedure entry point [...] could not be located in the dynamic link library: Kernel32.dll

Googling around I have found that these types of errors seem to be related to the program trying to access some old functionality in Kernel32.dll (possibly related to winsock), link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300179

Now I have no idea why this would happen, the program is compiled and works perfectly on an x64 Win7 computer, using - as far as I know - standard modern Windows programming practices. It is a console (service) application.

I'm thinking this is some incorrect setting somewhere which when explained is super easy to fix but that I have no idea of. A simple Hello World program compiled with the same settings had no problems running.

The program is using the VS2010 x64 SP1 runtime (installed on the server), and also an external API that in turn uses VS2012 runtime (also installed on the server). The dll files of the external API are in the same folder as the exe.

Comment: Could it be that there is an additional Kernel32.dll somewhere that is found and loaded instead of the system's?

Comment: Are you sure your program is not calling any Windows API function that is not available on Windows Server 2008?

Comment: Also you could use dependency walker to inspect your program for any missing stuff on the Windows server 2008 machine.

Comment: Good ideas, I will look into it. As for Windows API functions not available, is there any "easy" way to check that? I mean my program must have hundreds if not thousands of winapi calls, and then we have the external API that for all I know call even more.